# Any good techniques for designing copy constructor for class with some pointers and many data members

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I am faced with a class that must use a few pointers (due to reliance on an old library, it is not easy to use smart pointers here) and the class also contains a large amount of non-pointer data members that may grow as the project progresses.

Because of the pointers, I want to write my own copy constructor.  Because of tedium and difficulty in maintenance, I do not want to write out an initialization list that includes all the non-pointer data members and update it each time a new member is added.

It would be great if I could somehow rely on the default copy constructor and then just modify it for the few pointers, but I am not sure that this is possible?  Is there a way to do this or some other technique for dealing with this situation?

Some thoughts that may answer my own question.

The data members could by places in a separate class.  Then the original class could just contain one object of the data class and do a default copy of it.

Anything better?

Comment: Why or how does the old library inhibit the use of smart pointers in your type?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas The classes implement their own reference counting and all use virtual constructors.  Maybe it is not as bad as I think, but seems difficult to work with to me.

Comment: *I do not want to write out an initialization list that includes all the non-pointer data members and update it each time a new member is added.* I can't resist: Tough. Whether you initialize in the initializer list versus body is a bit of a personal preference issue (but most prefer the initializer list). What's not personal preference is that each and every member must be initialized or your code is strongly at risk of being deficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class doesn't own the raw pointers, just shallow copy them and call it all good.

If your class *does* own the pointers, go ahead and use an appropriate smart pointer and pass the raw pointer from it into your external library's API.

Finally if you and the library share ownership, ditch the library and find one with a sane interface. Or if you absolutely must, put the pointer members of your class into a `special_library_pointer_holder` class that knows how to properly copy/assign/etc each pointer than it holds with respect to your external library and then contain just the `special_library_pointer_holder` in your original class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach here is to let smart pointers do the job and follow [The Rule Of Zero](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/rule-of-zero).